# jquery animate not working properly when I set let 0px

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Below is the code which actually slides the div, sliding right to left is working fine ,but when I am sliding from left to right. its giving some shake. because

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:100px;width:100px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="cont" style="position:relative;width:205px;left:0px;top:0px">
      <div class="x" id="x_1" style="float:left;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;"></div>
      <div class="x" id="x_2" style="float:left;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="clik me1" data-info="1" id="click1"/>
<input type="button" value="clik me2" data-info="2" id="click2"/>
<script>
    $("#click1,#click2").bind('click',function(){
     var id = $(this).data("info");
     if(id == 2) {
        $(".cont").animate({left:'-100px'},500,'linear');
     } else {
        $(".cont").animate({left:'0px'},4000,'linear');  
        //above line actually not animating from -100px to 0px , its animating to -100px to -109px and then its animating to 0px. I want to know why its happening. 
     }
    });
</script>
```

in below url you can find the script

there is a problem with my chrome browser. its not a valid bug
http://jsbin.com/ukakah/2/edit

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 25.0.1364.172. Which browser do you use?

Comment: I use chrome, observe in chrome developer tool bar inspecting div 'cont' and see how left property is changing when its animating to 0px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ukakah/5/edit

```
$("#click1, #click2").on('click', function() {
    var animTo = this.id=='click1' ? 0 : 100 ;
    $(".cont").stop().animate({left: -animTo },500,'linear');    
});
```

Good to have `.stop()` to prevent animation buildups, and with a Ternary Operator this is all you need. (No `data` required.)

Comment: I have mistakenly kept that css({left:'0px';}), I have edited now.even in your example I am getting that shake.

Comment: there is a problem with my chrome browser in my system. even with out stop its working fine in another system same version of chrome. its wired

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
$(".cont").css({left:'0px'}).animate({left:'0px'},4000,'linear');
```

to

```
$(".cont").animate({left:'0px'},4000,'linear');
```

You are changing the left property before you animate hence the jump.

jsbin edited http://jsbin.com/ukakah/6/edit#/ukakah/7/edit